# Cómo imprimo la cantidad de números entre dos enteros que son múltiplos de 3

Tags: c#, bucle-for

```
using System;

namespace actForClase5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int li = 0;
            int ls = 0;
            int pausa = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Limite Inferior: ");
            li = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Limite Superior: ");
            ls = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for(int i = li; i < ls; i++)//i++ es para aumentar de uno en uno.
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0)//si el reciduo es cero ese numero es multiplo de 3
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " Es multiplo de 3 ");
                }

                //muestra 100 lineas cada enter hasta que termine el programa.
                pausa = pausa + 1;
                if (pausa == 100)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Presione Enter para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    pausa = 0;
                }
            }
           
            //ESTAS LINEAS SIEMPRE VAN AL FINAL.
            Console.WriteLine("Presione Enter para terminar");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Cómo hago para que en vez de que me muestre los números múltiplos de 3, me imprima la cantidad de números que hay en ese rango?

Comment: En una sola línea: `ls/3-(li-1)/3`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías llevar un contador que se incremente cada vez que se encuentra un número múltiplo de 3:

```
...
int contador = 0;
for(int i = li; i < ls; i++)//i++ es para aumentar de uno en uno.
{
   if (i % 3 == 0)//si el reciduo es cero ese numero es multiplo de 3
   {
      // Incrementa el contador
      contador++;
   }

   //muestra 100 lineas cada enter hasta que termine el programa.
   pausa = pausa + 1;
   if (pausa == 100)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Presione Enter para continuar");
      Console.ReadLine();
      pausa = 0;
   }
}

//Imprime la cantidad de números múltiplos de 3 en el rango dado
Console.WriteLine($"Existen {contador} números multiplos de 3 en [{li},{ls})");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un código usando **Linq**:

```
var cont = Enumerable.Range(li, ls).Where(n => n % 3 == 0).Count();

Console.WriteLine(cont.ToString());
```

Lo que se hace aquí es crear una lista de elementos donde el primer elemento corresponde al limite inferior y el último al límite superior, posteriormente se pregunta por todos los elemento que son divisibles por **3** y se hace un conteo de estos, devolviéndose así el total de números divisibles por **3**.

Por ejemplo si el límite inferior fuera **1** y el límite superior fuera **10** se creará una lista con todos los números del **1** al **10** y se filtrarán los elementos **3**, **6**, **9** que son los divisibles por **3** devolviéndose entonces el total de números que cumplen con esta condición.

```
var cont = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(n => n % 3 == 0).Count();
//Devuelve 3, que es el total de números divisibles por 3 que hay en ese rango
```

Debes incluir en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```